# How do I count the objects in an NSArray that have a certain value?

Tags: cocoa, nsarray

I have an NSArray populated with 0's and 1's. How can I return the number of 0's in the array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate through the array and count the things you're looking for.

Assuming you have an `NSArray` populated with `NSNumber`s:

```
NSArray* array = ... ; // populate array
NSUInteger count = 0;
for (NSNumber* number in array)
{
    if ([number intValue] == 0)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your application, you might consider using an [NSCountedSet](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

When it comes time to get the count of a certain type of object, you can just use the countForObject: instance method.

Probably a little too heavy for your current problem, but may be useful for others looking for similar solution.

Comment: This is precisely what NSCountedSet is for. You can make one from an array with `[[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array]` — then you can ask it for the count of any object in the array.

Answer (score 4):

A little perverted solution :)

```
NSUInteger zeros_count(NSArray *array) {
  NSUInteger sum = 0;
  for (NSNumber *number in array)
    sum += [number intValue];
  return [array count] - sum;
}
```

Comment: I love it. I want to use it to mess with my co-workers' minds.

Answer (score 4):

KeyValueCoding

```
int count = [array count] - [[array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.intValue"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a counter, set it to 0, loop through the array and if the element is 0, increment the counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* array = [[NSArray alloc] ...]; ; // put data into the array

NSUInteger arrayWithValue = 0;

for (NSNumber* number in array)

{

if ([number intValue] == NUMBERYOUARELOOKINGFOR)

    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! I missed that :/

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *arrayWithOnesAndZeros = @[@0, @0, @1, @1, @0, @1, @1, @0, @1];
NSUInteger numberOfZeros = [[NSCountedSet setWithArray:arrayWithOnesAndZeros]countForObject:@0];
```

This is a perfect method of you at runtime know very little of the object that you want to count, so instead of `@0` you can put `anyKindOfObjectWithUnknownValueOrType` there instead.